# Laravel - Can't seem to login with seeded users

Tags: php, laravel

I am making an SPA with Laravel and I have a seeder for my users. The seeder seems to seed my database fine. For every user the password is the same 12345678 that I set with Hash:make. But when I try to login it doesn't work while the users are clearly in the database(can't check the password since it's hashed). So I tried to register some users, and the strange thing is that the users that are registered can login just fine. My mind is blown, I have been looking at this for days now so it's time to ask for some help.

I checked the payload for the request and it matches the input exactly. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the seeder but I can't figure it out. Also it used to work with seeded data just fine, but I am no longer in possesion of the old seeders.

**Database Seeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Seed the users
        $this->call(UserSeeder::class);

        //seed the campaigns
        $this->call(CampaignSeeder::class);

        //seed the campaign users
        $this->call(UserCampaignSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

**User Seeder**

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "Test1";
        $user->email = "test1@gmail.com";
        $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
        $user->save();

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "Test2";
        $user->email = "test2@gmail.com";
        $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
        $user->save();

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "Test3";
        $user->email = "test3@gmail.com";
        $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
        $user->save();

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "Test4";
        $user->email = "test4@gmail.com";
        $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
        $user->save();

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "Test5";
        $user->email = "test5@gmail.com";
        $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
        $user->save();

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "Test6";
        $user->email = "test6@gmail.com";
        $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
        $user->save();

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "Test7";
        $user->email = "test7@gmail.com";
        $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
        $user->save();

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "Test8";
        $user->email = "test8@gmail.com";
        $user->password = Hash::make("12345678");
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

**Auth Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

    class AuthController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Create a new AuthController instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
        }

        public function register(Request $request)
        {
            $user = User::create([
                'name'    => $request->username,
                'email'    => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]);

            $token = auth('api')->login($user);

            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }

        /**
         * Get a JWT via given credentials.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function login()
        {
            $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

            if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
            }

            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }

        /**
         * Get the authenticated User.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function me()
        {
            return response()->json(auth('api')->user());
        }

        /**
         * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function logout()
        {
            auth('api')->logout();

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
        }

        /**
         * Refresh a token.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        public function refresh()
        {
            return $this->respondWithToken(auth('api')->refresh());
        }

        /**
         * Get the token array structure.
         *
         * @param  string $token
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        protected function respondWithToken($token)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'access_token' => $token,
                'user' => $this->guard()->user(),
                'token_type' => 'bearer',
                'expires_in' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60
            ]);
        }

        public function guard()
        {
            return Auth::Guard('api');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `bcrypt()` instead of `Hash`? If not, try `$user->password = bcrypt("12345678");`, and see if it works, please...

Comment: Or try just plain `password` instead of manually hashing it. See in your `register` method of the AuthController, no hashing is happening. It is done behind the scenes.

Comment: Make sure your User model doesn't have a mutator function that automatically hashes the password. I've done this a number of times myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thinks the problem is that you are not properly importing `Hash` on your seeder. However, you can simply use `bcrypt()` instead of `Hash`. Please, try:

```
$user->password = bcrypt("12345678");
```

and see if it works, please.

And also, make sure your User model doesn't have a mutator function that automatically hashes the password, as @ceejayoz brilliantly pointed out in the comments - if this is the case, just seed users using plain text passwords.

Comment: @MikeOttink I'm glad that helped point in the right direction. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Your login function has an error instead of a [comparison operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `==` or `===` you used assignment `=`, try

```php
        public function login()
        {
            $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

            // just use the returned boolean value
            if (!auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
            }

            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }
```

Comment: if the auth attempt is true, return unauthorized?

Comment: I don't think the use of the assignment operator in OP's code is a mistake. They need the `$token` assigned.

Comment: yeah! sorry for that... I missed a boolean negation there

Comment: @ceejayoz as far as I know attempt returns a boolean not a token: from laravel docs: "The attempt method will return `true` if authentication was successful. Otherwise, `false` will be returned."

Comment: @emont01 OP looks to be using https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth which returns a JWT token when using `attempt()`. See https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/auth-guard/#attempt and https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/.